# What is the proper way to link to a refinery page from a custom layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I would like to link to a page created under Pages in RefineryCMS from a custom layout. I know that I could hard code the link but would like the flexibility to follow the page if it is moved around in the site structure.

For example if the site starts out with the structure like this:

```
|- Join Our Team
|- About Us
   |- History
```

And the client moves Join Our Team under About us:

```
|- About Us
   |- History
   |- Join Our Team
```

And Join Our Team is linked in the custom template how should the link be coded so that it will not break when moved?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see your routes (and their respective names) by running `bundle exec rake routes`. Do you see any refinery routes in there?

Comment: Each page is ran through the pages routes so you don't have individual routes for each page or at least this is how I understand how RefineryCMS works.

Answer (score 0):

You need some unique way to identify the page. Is it `Refinery::Page.find(1)`? Or is it `Refinery::Page.where(slug: 'foo').first`? Keep in mind that as the page is "moved" about or edited, the slug, title and content might change.

Once you know which page you want and saved it in `@target_page`, then it's simply `link_to 'Page', @target_page.url`.

Comment: I can find the page by `Refinery::Page.by_title("Agriculture")` but then when I try to get `url_marketable` an error is thrown `undefined method 'url_marketable' for ...`. Assigning anything to `@page` will override the current page. I am testing out a new approach using the **copywriting** engine. This should at least allow the admin to update links in the layout.

Comment: The variable name could be anything you wish, of course. I've changed it in the answer so it doesn't clash.